# How to perform encryption of password using sha2 before saving password to database?

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com

I am saving password to database in my application.
But now I want to save encrypted password to database.
How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Apex Crypto Class, that will help.
It has all required methods and exceptions etc.
Refer this link -> [Crypto Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm)

Comment: I want to use sha2 alogrithm for encryption. but in Crypto service there is no provision for sha2, Crypto class only uses AES algorithm.
is there any hint ?

Comment: Crypto class has a method `sign(algorithmName, input, privateKey)` here algorithmName is of String that is used for name of the algorithm you want to use.

Comment: Follow the same link I have given in the answer.

Comment: Thanks Vivek,

one more thing using sign() we can encrypt and generate hash using RSA SHA256.
but how to decrypt encrypted message by sign() ?

Comment: Here is a simple example for encrypting and encrypting

Comment: `Blob cryptoKey = Crypto.generateAesKey(256);

// Generate the data to be encrypted.
 Blob data = Blob.valueOf('Test data to encrypted');
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES256', cryptoKey, data);
 Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES256', cryptoKey, encryptedData);

 String decryptedDataString = decryptedData.toString();`

Use your algorithmName instead of **AES256**